# Encountered the "Error calling sync triggers (TooManyRequests)" error when running "func azure functionapp publish" for a Python Function App in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-linux

I encountered the  `Error calling sync triggers (TooManyRequests)` error when running `func azure functionapp publish...` for a Python Function App in Azure. Encountered this error consistently after trying to publish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: This problem was caused by my stopping the Function App in Portal. After re-starting the Function App, the problem disappeared!

Comment: That was the exactly the same issue I had. as soon as i saw this i remembered i turned the azure function off.

Comment: Didn't help me. Guess there's many reasons this could fail and I can't find any *useful* logs of what's happening.

Comment: That was em, thanks. It's weird you can't deploy a turned off app