# How to debug a failed triggers sync for an Azure Function deployment?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm deploying my Azure Function in Python v2 using the CLI with `func azure functionapp publish [function_name]`, but I get an error saying `Error calling sync triggers`.

**Debug information**

I would like to debug this, but I found no useful information. We have:

- The CLI. Just says `Error calling sync triggers (BadRequest)`, no details.
- Activity log. There's an item in the Azure Portal -> Function App -> Activity log saying that *Sync Web Apps Function Triggers* failed. There's a JSON attached, but it only says `InternalServerError`. Here's the [relevant portion of the JSON](https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/143276c879a77db47c15d965c34b13b5).

Can somehow access more information? I'm not only after the solution to my current specific problem, but a way for me to be able to debug future problems too. As this one might be caused by Function App misconfiguration, Python problems or even internal Azure problems. There are similar problems on SO already, e.g. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547042/cannot-deploy-azure-function-error-calling-sync-triggers), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851673/encountered-the-error-calling-sync-triggers-toomanyrequests-error-when-runni), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212651/azure-functionapp-publish-failing-on-syncing-triggers), each one with the same symptom but a different underlying problem.

**App configuration**

- `AzureWebJobsStorage` is properly set.
- I've tried restarting the app, doesn't help.
- Here are the python [`requirements.txt`](https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/d4be51b87b8fc2ac7eba2d6a23bbe6bb), I'm thinking some new Python code caused this as the deploy used to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. I reported the problem to Azure support. After one week of unproductive discussion they admitted the problem was on their side end escalated it to the product engineering team. From my experience when Azure support tells you did nothing wrong and the problem is on their side - this is the worst thing you can hear from them. You will probably have to wait forever unless you fix the problem on your own.

I'm guessing there might be various reasons for that problem but what helped in my case was general OS update (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and specifically I guess the azure-functions-core-tools-4 package from version

```
ii  azure-functions-core-tools-4  4.0.4895-1                              amd64        Azure Function Core Tools v4
```

to

```
ii  azure-functions-core-tools-4  4.0.5455-1                              amd64        Azure Function Core Tools v4
```

and redeploying the function.